# Triple Nested Navigators w/ React-Navigation and Typescript in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am writing an app in which I have a base Stack, that contains a StartupScreen, another Stack with two AuthScreens, and then finally a Tab Navigator.

As a quick example, this looks like this:

```
export type AppStackParamsList = {
  StartupScreen: undefined;
  AuthStack: NavigatorScreenParams<AuthStackParamsList>;
  HomeTabs: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeTabsParamsList>;
};
const Stack = createStackNavigator<AppStackParamsList>();

<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
        name="StartupScreen"
        component={StartupScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthStack" component={AuthStack} />
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Here is HomeTabs:

```
export type HomeTabsParamsList = {
  HomeStack: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamsList>;
};

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator<HomeTabsParamsList>();
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Tabs.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And finally HomeStack

```
export type HomeStackParamsList = {
    HomeScreen: undefined;
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<HomeStackParamsList>();
const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

The start up screen is shown initially and does some work to find out if there's a user, and if so, then navigate to the HomeTabs, otherwise, navigate to the AuthStack which contains a sign in and sign up screen.

```
type Props = StackScreenProps<AppStackParamsList, "StartupScreen">;

...

 if (auth) {
      navigation.navigate("HomeTabs");
    } else {
      navigation.navigate("AuthStack", { screen: "SignInScreen" });
    }
```

The AuthStack is working fine, and from StartupScreen I am able to navigate to AuthStack no problem.

My problem is coming in at navigating to the HomeTabs. in the above conditional, when I try to navigate to HomeTabs from StartupScreen, i am shown the typescript warning:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: "StartupScreen"; key?: string | undefined; params: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { key: string; params?: NavigatorScreenParams<...> | undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }'
```

I'm extremely confused by this as I'm even getting proper code completion for the screens that are nested in the Tab Navigator.

For example, if I type:

```
navigation.navigate("HomeTabs", { screen: "HomeStack" });
```

VScode is able to autocomplete this as if TS is aware the screen is there.

I thought by using the nested navigator pattern all the way up the navigator tree, this would be no problem, but clearly I have something wrong here and I have a feeling it's because it's a nested Tab navigator and not a nested Stack navigator, but I'm not sure of that.

Just to reiterate, the pattern I have is, from the bottom-most stack going UP:

```
export type HomeStackParamsList = {
    HomeScreen: undefined;
}
export type HomeTabsParamsList = {
  HomeStack: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamsList>;
};
And finally:

export type AppStackParamsList = {
  StartupScreen: undefined;
  AuthStack: NavigatorScreenParams<AuthStackParamsList>;
  HomeTabs: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeTabsParamsList>;
};
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

Maybe I have the entire philosophy wrong?

Comment: Did you resolved your problem? Error when you try to navigate to other screen, right?

Comment: @VuPhung I did not resolve the problem from the highest level of navigator. I am currently using navigation.navigate("HomeTabs" as any) to navigate and avoid error. I have not found a way to make the top most navigation object recognize the lower nested navigators.